# XPath - find an element based on its parent's sibling's child's text

Tags: xml, xpath

I have read many online threads and tried many XPath combinations, but it seems that whatever I did, I'm still not able to find my custom XPath for my element. Here is my HTML code, and I need to find the XPath for the highlighted/stared item.

TIA

```
<div style="display: -moz-box;">
<label for="employeeSel">Select&nbsp;Employees</label>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select id="employeeSel" multiple name="employeeSel" size="10" style="min-width:120px; padding-left:0.4em; padding-right:0.4em">...</select>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                **<a onclick="selectAll('employeeSel',true)">Select&nbsp;All</a>**
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[xpath issue screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGyDT.png)

Comment: I know and I am trying to fix it

Comment: What XPath have you tried so far? Also, you will need to make sure your "HTML" is in fact valid XML

Comment: Unfortunately the input file is HTML and not _well-formed_ XML, because of the `multiple` pseudo-attribute on the `select` element.

Comment: hence my issue, our previous developer was not a fan for unique element.

Comment: so far this one is work for me, but my automatic software seems not able to "Click" on it.
//*[@valign='top']//preceding::select[@id='employeeSel']

Comment: Are you sure that "reading many online threads" and "trying many combinations" is the right way to master a programming language? Have you tried reading a good book instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the `a` element, use the following XPath-1.0 expression:

```
//div[contains(@style,'display:')]/table/tbody/tr/td[@valign='top'][preceding-sibling::td[select/@id='employeeSel']]/a
```

---

A second approach is this:

```
//div[contains(@style,'display:')]/table/tbody/tr/td[select/@id='employeeSel']/following-sibling::td[@valign='top']/a
```

Both expression should return the same element `a`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this still not unique enough for the item. There are still 3 instances with your answer.

Comment: @ladyW: I changed the attribute from `@name` to `@id`. This should do the trick. It's been an issue with the `multiple` pseudo-attribute.

Comment: OMG, thank you!!! it took me all day just get what I have above, and you solved less then few minutes!!!